# Repairing 1000W wall heater: Burnt cable, serious issue?

Tags: repair, heater, power, cables

European here. I'm repairing a simple 1000W wall heater (brand: BEHA) - about 10 years old. The heater itself is in good condition, but the thermostat panel (completely detachable) and its connections, less so. There is a power problem in which we have to wiggle the cables somewhat for it to power on. Taking a closer look, it seems one of the cables (the brown cable pictured below) has been having some heat issues. Notice the black, burnt color, and its oxidized (?) attachment.

My question; does this burnt cable suggest some serious issue, or is this normal for a 10 year old wall heater?

I'm suspecting it is causing the power problem, and plan to replace it and its attachment.

Thanks.

[image: overview]
[image: close look 1]
[image: close look 2]

Comment: I would totally expect to see this especially because "we have to wiggle the cables somewhat". That points to a poor connection, and bad connections can arc and looked "burnt" especially on high current loads (like a heater).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like a simple poor termination. Pretty common unfortunately.

If you are replacing that harness (I also see damaged/nicked wire) then you should be fine considering the rest of the unit is in good shape.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but future readers should also note the blue wire has 2 nicks going through the insulation, as well as brown wire (looks purple to me) also had a crease/pinched section. If this wasn't a replacement, those problems need to be addressed as well as the burnt end.